# Set div to cover all window size, minus menu bar height, without scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow, window-resize

I'm trying to build a slider plugin from scratch because I need it to have some specific behavior that is hard to find in other plugins. Anyway, one of the requirements is that it takes all the space available in the page, minus the menu bar height.

This is an example I set up: https://jsfiddle.net/5ujqw94n/

To set the size of the size I call this function:

```
adjustSizes: function(that) {
  var w = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
  var h = $(window).height() - $('header').height();
  console.log('window inner w', $(window).innerWidth());
  that.$elem.width(w);
  that.$elem.height(h);
  console.log('window inner w', $(window).innerWidth());
  console.log('document client w', document.body.parentNode.clientWidth);
}
```

I also call the function when resizing the window. What happens is that when the page is loaded, it shows the scrollbars, but resizing the window makes them disappear.

In the function I put some `console.log` to track the window width and noticed that there's a 15px difference after the resizing is applied. I thought this could have had something to do with the scrollbars and searching arouns seems this is the case.

I'm not sure how to solve it. Putting `overflow: hidden` kind of works, but I was hoping for another approach because this feels like a workaround.

For example, in this other [page](http://professeurcyclope.arte.tv/usine-a-gaz/chapter/les_jolis_flots.html) everything seems to work as I want to and there's no `overflow: hidden` in the body.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that's (kind of) working at least in chromium.

Remove borders from `.page-container` and modify `.slider-container`

```
.slider-container {
    border: 0px solid yellow;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Now pour some `body { margin: 0; }` on top of it and serve refreshed.

*What baffles me however is why the borders are causing the horizontal scroll bars **even with `box-sizing: border-box;` stated**... hope it helps anyways.*

Comment: thanks, this has been really helpful. 
I didn't really need the border and was using them for debugging. I'm as baffled as you are, but probably there's a good reason as to why it behaves that way.
By the way, I also found out that I can remove the `position: absolute` from the `slider-container` and just use `margin: auto`. I updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ujqw94n/1/ (hope I'm not missing anything else this way)

Comment: yep that works because the div is implicitly set to width 100% which caps at max with 960px and thus is centered by the margin auto on wider screens. I would add width: 100% to the image in the slider though ;-)